# Matching multiple arguments in a string using regex

Tags: python, regex

Suppose that I have following string:

```
mystr = """
<p>Some text and another text. </p> ![image_file_1][image_desc_1] some other text. 
<p>some text</p> 
![image_file_2][image_desc_2] and image: ![image_file_3][image_desc_3] 
test case 1: ![dont_match_1]
test case 2: [dont_match_2][dont_match_3]
finally: ![image_file_4][image_desc_4]
"""
```

I can get `image_file_X`'s using the following code:

```
import re
re.findall('(?<=!\[)[^]]+(?=\]\[.*?\])', mystr)
```

I want to capture `image_desc_X`'s but following does not work:

```
re.findall('(?!\[.*?\]\[)[^]]+(?=\])', mystr)
```

Any suggestions? If I can get both `image_file`'s and `image_desc`'s using one command that would be even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following approach:

```
result = re.findall(r'!\[([^]]+)\]\[([^]]+)\]', mystr)
print(result)
```

The output:

```
[('image_file_1', 'image_desc_1'), ('image_file_2', 'image_desc_2'), ('image_file_3', 'image_desc_3'), ('image_file_4', 'image_desc_4')]
```

Comment: There is no need to express existence of `!` with a positive lookbehind. Literal `!` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use:

```
for match in re.finditer(r"!\[(.*?)\]\[(.*?)]", mystr):
    print match.group(1)
    print match.group(2)
```

---

output:

```
image_file_1
image_desc_1
image_file_2
image_desc_2
image_file_3
image_desc_3
image_file_4
image_desc_4
```

---

[DEMO](https://eval.in/782126)

Comment: Are you sure case-insensitivity flag should be set here?

Comment: It came by default...I'll remove it, tks!